# Shopware - How to get products using App Credentials?

Tags: shopware6

I created App in Shopware and able to get apiKey, secretKey, shopUrl and shopId. I want to get all my products using these credentials.

This is my code

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://shopware.example.com/store-api/product",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "sw-access-key: SW234C1LVA010CWHDD34WK1TMW"
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    print_r($data);
}
```

and I am getting error like this

```
Array
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [status] => 412
                    [code] => FRAMEWORK__ROUTING_SALES_CHANNEL_NOT_FOUND
                    [title] => Precondition Failed
                    [detail] => No matching sales channel found.
                    [meta] => Array
                        (
                            [parameters] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

When I using API key from settings page API I am able to get products.

[image]

But how to use App credentials (App key, secret key, shop URL) and get products

Answer (score 0):

You should have gotten the API key during App registration:

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-base-guide#confirmation-request

Did you try that one? If it does not work for the store API you might want to use the admin API.